Flutter firebase google sign in error BAD_TOKEN_REQUEST
I have this code where I want the user to log in to my application using google sign in from firebase, the code works fine initially and I left it for days, when I came back and re-check the application, this error shows up
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(19556): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17@d53de4
D/EGL_emulation(19556): app_time_stats: avg=399.85ms min=3.54ms max=10250.70ms count=27
W/Auth    (19556): [GoogleAuthUtil] [GoogleAuthUtil] error status:BAD_TOKEN_REQUEST with method:getTokenWithDetails
E/flutter (19556): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(exception, BAD_REQUEST, null, null)
E/flutter (19556): #0      GoogleSignInApi.getAccessToken (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:250:7)
E/flutter (19556): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19556): #1      GoogleSignInAndroid.getTokens.<anonymous closure> (package:google_sign_in_android/google_sign_in_android.dart:68:15)
E/flutter (19556): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19556): #2      GoogleSignInAccount.authentication (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:95:9)
E/flutter (19556): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19556): #3      _AuthScreenState.signInWithGoogle (package:drive_prototype1/screens/auth.dart:114:45)
E/flutter (19556): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19556): 

here is my google sign in method
 void signInWithGoogle() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
    
    setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

also I already make sure that I put the SHA to the firebase and downloaded the latest google-services.json

Have you enabled the authentication provider in Firebase's Authentication tab?

if you mean the google sign in authentication provider, than yes. As I said, the code works just fine initially but it suddenly give me that error when I re-check it after leaving it for a few days

any solutions  in this

I have the same issue. It seems to have nothing to do with my code as it worked like that before and now after some time without changes it doesn't work anymore.

same issue on my side
